# Definition of opposite category

Tags: category-theory

I don't quite understand the definition of opposite category.  Wikipedia defines $\mathcal{C}^\text{op}$ to be the category formed by 'reversing' morphisms. So for instance, in Grps, given a groups $G,H$ and a homomorphism $f: G \to H$, what does reversing $f$ mean?  Do we reverse $f$ into a homomorphism $H \to G$?

Answer (score 29):

If $C$ is a category, we want to construct a new category $C^{op}$. To do so, we need to describe its objects, the set of morphisms between each of its objects and its composition rule $\circ_{C^{op}}$.

- The objects of $C^{op}$ are just the objects of $C$.
- If $a$ and $b$ are two objects of $C^{op}$,  then the set $\hom_{C^{op}}(a,b)$ is **defined** to be $\hom_C(b,a)$. Notice that this makes sense, for $a$ and $b$ are objects of $C$, so it makes sense to talk about $\hom_C(b,a)$.
- If $a$, $b$ and $c$ are three objects of $C^{op}$ and $f\in\hom_{C^{op}}(a,b)$ and $g\in\hom_{C^{op}}(b,c)$, then the above definition means that $f\in\hom_C(b,a)$ and $g\in\hom_C(c,b)$, so it makes sense to compute the composition $f\circ_C g$ in $C$, which gives an element of $\hom_C(c,a)$. This last set is, by definition $\hom_{C^{op}}(a,c)$. We define the composition of $C^{op}$ so that $$g\circ_{C^{op}}f:= f\circ_Cg.$$

Let us give a concrete example. Suppose $C$ is the category which has exactly two objects, which are called $a$ and $b$ and three morphisms in all: the two identities and one morphism $f:a\to b$. Then $C^{op}$ has again $\{a,b\}$ as set of objects, and has exactly three morphisms: the two identities and one morphism from $b$ to $a$, which is $f$.

A slightly less silly example is the following: suppose $C$ is a category which has exactly one object, which I will call $x$. Then the set $\hom_C(x,x)$ is a set endowed with an associative multiplication admitting an identity element: it is what one calls a monoid. The opposite category $C^{op}$ has, again, exactly one object, which is still $x$, and has a monoid $\hom_{C^{op}}(x,x)$. Can you describe this monoid in terms of $\hom_C(x,x)$?

Comment: Perhaps it's worth giving some example where such a construction is interesting, so that OP faster catches its importance?

Comment: This construction is purely formal, and as such it has very little importance, really... Its role is to allow us to speak of contravariant functors and covariant functors uniformly, which is not that important.

Comment: Ok, that's good to know - thanks

Comment: Well in $C^{op}$, the the morphisms $hom_{C^{op}}(x, x)$ are exactly the morphisms $hom_C(x, x,)$, but in $C^{op}$ $f \circ g$ is defined to be $g \circ f$ in $C$.  Does that sound right?

Comment: The construction is more than just a formality. Non-commutative geometry for instance is defined as the study of an opposite category. Pontrajyn duality is the establishment of an equivalence between the opposite of a category and a familiar category. So is Stone duality. The fact that the opposite of the category of sets is equivalent to the category of complete atomic boolean algebras is also an interesting example of duality. So, the opposite construction is very simple and useful, but it hides some interesting subtleties.

Comment: @IttayWeiss, the "study of the opposite category" is just the study of the actual category: there is no content in doing that.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez there is content in understanding the opposite category in terms of more familiar categories. I think the examples I gave illustrate this.

Comment: Would you say that there is some content in the construction of the opposite ring of a ring?

Comment: How can we know that there exists a morphism from $b\rightarrow a$?