# What's the definition of morphism in a dual category?

Tags: category-theory

$
\newcommand{\cat}{\mathbf}
\newcommand{\RR}{\mathrm R}
$

If there exist a morphism 
$$f:\RR \rightarrow [0,+\infty] ,f : x\mapsto x^2+1$$
 in a category $\cat{Set}$. In particular, $f$ is not injective nor a surjective.

In the category of $\cat{Set^{op}}$, the  $f$ change into 
$$f^{op}:[0,+\infty]\rightarrow \RR $$

This raises a question :
$$f^{op}:x\mapsto ??? $$

The definition must satisfy that:
$$
\cat {(C^{op})^{op}} = \cat C
$$

Comment: The discussion [at this other question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2092872/do-opposite-categories-always-exist) might be helpful to you. Short version: morphisms (and objects) are in general *purely abstract*; even though one category might have a very "concrete" interpretatoin, its opposite (which is defined purely formally) need not.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The morphism $f^{\mathrm{op}}$ is still the same function as $f$. In a category, the morphisms can be anything; they don't need to be functions. (For example, think about treating a poset like a category: there, the morphisms aren't functions either.) In particular, it is perfectly allowed to make up a category $\mathsf C$, where the objects of $\mathsf C$ are sets, and a morphism $f: X \to Y$ is actually a *function* $f: Y \to X$. (Can you see what composition has to be?) Then, the category $\mathsf C$ is just $\mathsf{Set}^{\mathrm{op}}$.

Comment: Why the morphism $f^{op}$ is still the same function as $f$? they have diffrent domain and codomain.

Comment: @xiang A morphism in $\mathbf{Set}^{\mathrm{op}}$ is *not* a function.

Comment: $$f^{op}:x\mapsto \begin{cases}
\pm \sqrt{x-1},&x>1  \\
nothing,&0\leq x<1
\end{cases}$$. Is it right?

Comment: That answer is mistaken.  A morphism need not be a function, because an object in a category need not be a set.  A morphism $f$ in a category is indeed the same as $f^{op}$ in the dual category, but its domain and codomain are switched.

Comment: @xiang: The domain of $f^\text{op}$ as a function need not be the same thing as the domain of $f^\text{op}$ as a morphism of a category.

Comment: @SixWingedSeraph My answer is not function, because in function each x maps to only one value, but in $f^{op}$,it x can maps to 0,1,2…… or more values .

Comment: @xiang: My point is that the morphism $f$ may not be a function.  It may merely be an arrow drawn on a piece of paper. There are examples in A slow introduction to categories (http://www.abstractmath.org/Word%20Press/?p=10130) and in the Wikibooks article on categories.  There is no question that you can assume that $f$ maps elements to elements -- its domain may not have elements. Similarly, $f^{op}$ may not "map" anything to anything, multivalued or otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

In $\mathbf{Set}^\text{op}$, $\hom(X, Y)$ is the set of all functions from $Y$ to $X$.

---

That said, there is an equivalent description: that $\hom(X,Y)$ is the set of all functions $\mathcal{P}(X) \to \mathcal{P}(Y)$ that preserve unions and intersections.

More precisely, $\mathbf{Set}^\text{op}$ is equivalent to the category whose objects are complete atomic boolean algebras and whose morphisms are functions that preserve all unions and intersections.

The bijection between the two descriptions associates to a function $f : Y \to X$ the function $f^* : \mathcal{P}(X) \to \mathcal{P}(Y)$ defined by
$$f^*(S) = \{ y \in Y \mid f(y) \in S \} $$

---

It may be interesting to note that there are naturally occurring categories where morphisms involve functions going the "wrong way". For example, in **Top**, the category of topological spaces and continuous maps, the homomorphisms $(|X|, \mathcal{S}) \to (|Y|, \mathcal{T})$ involve functions $|X| \to |Y|$ (i.e. a mapping on points) and also functions $\mathcal{T} \to \mathcal{S}$ (the inverse image of an open set is open).

A related notion is that of a locale. It's like a topological space, but without the set of points: a locale is just the frame of open 'sets'. So, in the category **Loc** of locales, a locale morphism $\mathcal{S} \to \mathcal{T}$ is a (structure preserving) function $\mathcal{T} \to \mathcal{S}$!