# Example of Dual Category That Makes No Sense (to me)

Tags: category-theory

Example of Dual Category That Seems to Makes No Sense

I have read the several entries on mathstackexchange concerning the definition of dual categories.  For a purely theoretical point of view, the definitions seem straight forward - until I try to apply them to some simple categories and then the results make no sense.

First of all, when dealing with morphs that are functions, "turning the arrows around" to form the dual category does not mean using the inverses of the functions (which may not exist) - it means using the exact same functions but with the domain and codomain switched.  (Right?)

Now take this example: suppose the category C contains the two objects A and B, where A represents the positive real numbers and B represents the negative real numbers. One morph from A to B is the function f which maps each positive real number to its negative square root.  So, 4 is mapped to -2, and 9 is mapped to -3, etc.

Now to form the dual of the category C which contains A, B, and f we just turn the arrows/morphs/functions around.  This means for numbers in B (which are negative) we take their negative square roots, because that is what the function f does.  But the square root of a negative number cannot be a positive real number, i.e, cannot be in A.  So the arrow, i.e. function, from B to A in the dual category cannot exist, or makes no sense.

Perhaps my problem is the language used in the definitions.  But what am I misunderstanding?

Comment: Morphisms in a category need not be mappings.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2092872/do-opposite-categories-always-exist.

Comment: Is there some reason you continually use the word "morphs"? This is not a term that is used in category theory. The common terms are "morphism" and "arrow" which are typically synonymous.

Comment: @Derek - Point well taken.

Comment: What you have in mind is that of a *concrete* category: a category $\mathcal{C}$ together with a faithful functor $U : \mathcal{C} \to \mathbf{Set}$. It is this functor $U$ that lets us treat $\mathcal{C}$ as a category whose objects are sets, and where elements of $\hom(X,Y)$  are functions with domain $X$ and codomain $Y$. Given such a thing, $\mathcal{C}^\text{op}$ doesn't become a concrete category until you pick a suitable $V : \mathcal{C}^\text{op} \to \mathbf{Set}$.

Comment: And it's worth noting, in connection with Hurkyl's comment, that *not every category can be made concrete*: this is proved for a particular category of interest in [a paper of Freyd](http://www.tac.mta.ca/tac/reprints/articles/6/tr6abs.html).

Comment: @Hurkyl, Is there a well defined relationship between the functors U and V in your example?

Comment: @MPitts: There does not have to be any relationship at all between $U$ and $V$. There *can* be in special cases, and I know of at least one general construction (basically given by composing with the contravariant power set functor), but this is by no means something forced upon you, and AFAIK is not something generally studied. In fact, almost the opposite is desired: one can get a lot of mileage out of a category for which there are fairly natural but unrelated $U$ and $V$, because it gives you two opposing viewpoints with which to study the category!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, we don't use "the analogous function" (e.g. "Take the negative square root") - we use *literally the same function*.

The morphism from $B$ to $A$ in the category $C^{op}$ is the function $$f: A\rightarrow B: a\mapsto-\sqrt{b}.$$ It doesn't matter that this is a function from $A$ to $B$, and not from $B$ to $A$; a morphism from one object to another does not in any way have to be a function from the underlying set of the first to the underlying set of the second (nor, in fact, do objects need to have underlying sets in the first place).

---

For a "bigger" but less ad-hoc example, that might be easier to think about: in the category **Set**$^{op}$, a morphism from $A$ to $B$ is a function in the usual sense from $B$ to $A$.

More natural, but more technical, examples include the homotopy category and the cobordism category.

---

It might be helpful at this point to consider a purely algebraic description of a category.

First, remember what (say) a group is: it's a set $G$ together with a binary operation $*$ on $G$, with some properties. It doesn't matter what the elements of $G$ are, and in fact we never talk about this - only the structure relating them is relevant.

OK, so along these lines, here's how to think about a category. First, let's ditch the objects for simplicity: we don't actually need them (objects can be conflated with their identity morphisms). A category, for us, is going to be a set $C$ (the set of morphisms) together with a **partial** (= not always defined) binary operation $*$ (composition), with the following properties:

- Associativity: If $(a*b)*c$ is defined, then so is $a*(b*c)$, and they are equal; and if $a*(b*c)$ is defined, then so is $(a*b)*c$, and they are equal.
- "Source" identities: For any $a$, there is a unique $e$ such that

  - $a*e$ is defined *($e$ is a morphism to the source of $a$)*.
  - $e*e$ is defined *($e$'s source and target are the same)*.
  - For all $b$, if $b*e$ is defined then $b*e=b$; and if $e*b$ is defined then $e*b=b$ *($e$ acts like an identity morphism)*.
- "Target" identities: the same as the above, but the first bullet says instead "$e*a$ is defined."

Note that this is purely algebraic, and we don't need to give any meaning to the elements of the set $C$.

Besides building intuition, this is a very fruitful idea: for example, it lets us define a group as *a one-object category where every morphism has an inverse*! If you unwind the picture above, you'll see that this means exactly that "$*$" is defined everywhere (since there's only one object), so there is only one identity morphism $e$, and associativity and inverses mean that this is just a group! This way of thinking of classical algebraic structures as categories with certain properties is incredibly fruitful, and leads to a number of useful generalizations; for instance, it motivates the definition of a [groupoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Groupoid#Category_theoretic) as a group but with multiple objects, which in turn lets us define fundamental groupoids which are often [better to work with than fundamental groups](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/175923/why-are-we-interested-in-the-fundamental-groupoid-of-a-space).

Comment: So, in the dual category, -2 maps to what??

Comment: @MPitts It doesn't. *A morphism need not be a function*. In the original category, a morphism from $X$ to $Y$ happened to be a function from $X$ to $Y$; in the opposite category, a morphism from $X$ to $Y$ happens to not be a function from $X$ to $Y$. The idea that morphisms need to be functions on the underlying sets is wrong.

Comment: @MPitts $-2$ is not known to the category. It isn't a "thing" in the category. There are only two things in a category, at its most basic: Morphisms and objects. $-2$ is neither in either category, your original $A,B$ category, nor its dual. Morphisms are not always maps or functions.

Comment: I understand that morphs need not be functions.  But they need to be something that is well defined.  What are they in the example I provided?

Comment: @MPitts "[they] need to be something." Not really, no. A morphism is just . . . a morphism, in the same way that an element of group is just . . . an element of a group.

Comment: In the category you described, there are two objects, $A,B$, and the morphisms between them. There is no "-2" to go to anything. It doesn't go anywhere. If $f$ is a morphism in $C$ from $A$ to $B$ then $f$ is a morphism in $C^{op}$ from $B$ to $A$. The dual category is "abstract nonsense."

Comment: But morphs in a well-defined category must be well defined.

Comment: @MPitts Yes, but that doesn't mean it has to mean anything. The morphism from $B$ to $A$ **is well-defined**, we just defined it: it's the function $f: A\rightarrow B: a\mapsto -\sqrt{a}$! **There is no rule saying that a morphism from $X$ to $Y$ needs to be a function from the underlying set of $X$ to the underlying set of $Y$.**

Comment: Think of it this way: in the polynomial ring $\mathbb{R}[x]$, what "is" the variable $x$?

Comment: Ok.  So the function f in the dual category is more like an abstract "thing" that doesn't directly relate to A or B.  Right?

Comment: @MPitts Exactly! A category is just a bundle of abstract data. Just like a group, *sometimes* these data have internal structure, but they need not in general.

Comment: @MPitts I've edited my answer to give an explicitly algebraic definition of a category, which should illuminate why the morphisms need not "mean" anything.

Comment: Thanks.  I understand dual categories better now, and the moniker "abstract nonsense" a lot better now (ha-ha).

Comment: You want a (not b) under the first square root sign, right?

Comment: @MPitts Yes, good catch.

Answer (score 5):

Let $\mathscr{C}$ be a category. The **opposite category** of $\mathscr{C}$ is the category $\mathscr{C}^{\mathrm{op}}$ where

- $\DeclareMathOperator{Ob}{Ob}\DeclareMathOperator{id}{id}\Ob(\mathscr{C}^{\mathrm{op}})=\Ob(\mathscr{C})$
- $\DeclareMathOperator{Hom}{Hom}\Hom_{\mathscr{C}^{\mathrm{op}}}(X, Y)=\Hom_{\mathscr{C}}(Y,X)$

That is, $\mathscr{C}^{\mathrm{op}}$ has the same objects as $\mathscr{C}$ and the same morphisms as $\mathscr{C}$. The statement "$f$ is a morphism $X\to Y$ in $\mathscr{C}^{\mathrm{op}}$" is the same statement as "$f$ is a morphism $Y\to X$ in $\mathscr{C}$."

For example, consider $\mathscr{C}=\mathsf{Set}$. Here, we have a function $f\in\Hom_{\mathsf{Set}}(\Bbb R^+,\Bbb R)$ given by $f(x)=\log(x)$. The function $f$ is also a morphism in $\mathsf{Set}^{\mathrm{op}}$, except now $f\in\Hom_{\mathsf{Set}^{\mathrm{op}}}(\Bbb R,\Bbb R^+)$ since $\Hom_{\mathsf{Set}^{\mathrm{op}}}(\Bbb R,\Bbb R^+)=\Hom_{\mathsf{Set}}(\Bbb R^+,\Bbb R)$.

In short, declaring that $f:X\to Y$ in $\mathsf{Set}^{\mathrm{op}}$ is to declare that $f$ is a map of sets with domain $Y$ and target $X$.

In your example, we have a category $\mathscr{C}$ where $\Ob(\mathscr{C})=\{\Bbb R^+,\Bbb R^-\}$ and we are told that one morphism $f\in\Hom_{\mathscr{C}}(\Bbb R^+,\Bbb R^-)$ is the map of sets $f:\Bbb R^+\to\Bbb R^-$ given by the formula $f(x)=-\sqrt{x}$.

The opposite category $\mathscr{C}^{\mathrm{op}}$ also contains this morphism except now $f\in\Hom_{\mathscr{C}^{\mathrm{op}}}(\Bbb R^-,\Bbb R^+)$.

It is possible that this $f$ is the only nontrivial morphism in $\mathscr{C}$, in which case we have an explicit description of $\mathscr{C}$:
\begin{align*}
\Ob(\mathscr{C}) &= \{\Bbb R^+, \Bbb R^-\} &
\Hom_{\mathscr{C}}(\Bbb R^+,\Bbb R^+) &= \{\id_{\Bbb R^+}\} &
\Hom_{\mathscr{C}}(\Bbb R^-, \Bbb R^-) &= \{\id_{\Bbb R^-}\} \\
&& \Hom_{\mathscr{C}}(\Bbb R^+,\Bbb R^-)&=\{f\} &
\Hom_{\mathscr{C}}(\Bbb R^-,\Bbb R^+) &=\varnothing
\end{align*}
This gives the explicit description of $\mathscr{C}^{\mathrm{op}}$:
\begin{align*}
\Ob(\mathscr{C^{\mathrm{op}}}) &= \{\Bbb R^+, \Bbb R^-\} &
\Hom_{\mathscr{C^{\mathrm{op}}}}(\Bbb R^+,\Bbb R^+) &= \{\id_{\Bbb R^+}\} &
\Hom_{\mathscr{C^{\mathrm{op}}}}(\Bbb R^-, \Bbb R^-) &= \{\id_{\Bbb R^-}\} \\
&& \Hom_{\mathscr{C^{\mathrm{op}}}}(\Bbb R^+,\Bbb R^-)&=\varnothing &
\Hom_{\mathscr{C^{\mathrm{op}}}}(\Bbb R^-,\Bbb R^+) &=\{f\}
\end{align*}
Note that here $\id_{\Bbb R^{\pm}}$ need not be a map of sets!

Comment: Maybe this is just a question on notation (or maybe itz more), but if we focus on f as a morphism in the dual category, is still accurate to write f:A -->B ? (See Noah's answer above.). If that notation is okay, in what sense have we "turned the arrows around"?

Comment: When we write $f:A\to B$ we need to assert which category we are working in. To say that $f:A\to B$ in $\mathscr{C}$ is to say that $f:B\to A$ in $\mathscr{C}^{\mathrm{op}}$.

Comment: See Mathstack question 693810 for a good discussion of these issues.

Answer (score 0):

I may be a little late to the party, but I'm having a tough time with categories as well (I've tried digging into the subject a few times over the past few years, I feel that I'm actually making some progress with "Category Theory for Programmers").  The notion that "the dual category simply is" doesn't really cut it for me, so with **SET** I'm thinking about it in the following way, someone please correct me if I'm wrong.

Given **SET** is sets and functions between them, I'm thinking that the morphisms in **SET**$^{OP}$ are equivalence classes indexed by the dual-sources.  While not every function has an inverse, the psuedo-inverse given by $f^{-1}(x) = \{y \,|\, f(y) = x\}$ is a well-defined, and seems to do the trick.  The new initial object is the equivalence where all elements are equivalent to one another, and the terminal object is the equivalence where nothing is equivalent to anything (not even itself).

Am I one the right track?  Is it more like "the dual category of **SET** is isomorphic to what I've described" or something?  I know you're "not supposed to care" about the morphisms, but when they're something as nice as functions I'd rather just grab 'em by the... unctions and have a more concrete intuition about it.

Comment: Nice perspective. I've also  read that the dual of Set is the Category of boolean algebras but don't quite understand the derivation. My interest is more programming oriented taking the category of types and functions (also cartesian closed): we can represent the dual category using the slice over the terminal object (the type void), so each type a is mapped to the unique morphine a -> void. Thus objects in the dual category can be interpreted as continuations and arrows as continuations transformers.