# The definition of contravariant hom functor

Tags: category-theory

Given a category $\mathbb{C}$ and its object $C$, the contravariant hom functor based at $C$ is a contravariant functor $hom_{\mathbb{C}}(-,C):\mathbb{C} \to Sets$, where $Sets$ is the category of sets, carrying a morphism $f:A \to B$ in $\mathbb{C}$ to the map $hom_\mathbb{C}(f,C):hom_\mathbb{C}(B,C) \to hom_\mathbb{C}(A,C)$ defined $\alpha \mapsto \alpha{f}$.

As we can use an alternative definition for any contravariant functor using a covariant functor from $\mathbb{C}^{op}$, my notes say as follows.

Given a category $\mathbb{C}$ and its object $C$, the contravariant hom functor based at $C$ is a ***covariant*** functor $hom_{\mathbb{C}}(-,C):\mathbb{C}^{op} \to Sets$, where $Sets$ is the category of sets, carrying a morphism $f:B \to A$ in $\mathbb{C}^{op}$ to the map $hom_\mathbb{C}(f,C):hom_\mathbb{C}(A,C) \to hom_\mathbb{C}(B,C)$ defined $\alpha \mapsto \alpha{f}$ (in $\mathbb{C}$).

I strongly believe this is a typo and it should read as follows.

Given a category $\mathbb{C}$ and its object $C$, the contravariant hom functor based at $C$ is a ***covariant*** functor $hom_{\mathbb{C}}(-,C):\mathbb{C}^{op} \to Sets$, where $Sets$ is the category of sets, carrying a morphism $f:B \to A$ in $\mathbb{C}^{op}$ to the map $hom_\mathbb{C}(f,C):hom_\mathbb{C}(B,C) \to hom_\mathbb{C}(A,C)$ defined $\alpha \mapsto \alpha{f}$ (in $\mathbb{C}$).

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You are completely right.

Comment: You are right, if the map $f: B\to A$ is in $\mathbb{C}^{op}$, then it's $hom(B,C)\to hom(A,C)$

Comment: @asdq Thank you so much

Comment: @Max Thank you for the confirmation

Comment: @Max in $\alpha \mapsto \alpha{f}$ Is ${f}$ defined as $f:B \to A$ or $f:A \to B$?

Comment: @Roland write it out to see : it can only be one of them (and you have to specify whether you're talking about $\mathbb{C}$ or $ \mathbb{C}^{op}$

Comment: @Max I'm confused because if $f:B \to A$ in $\mathbb{C}^{op}$ and $\alpha \in hom_\mathbb{C}(B,C)$ then the following concatenation wouldn't be possible: $\alpha \mapsto \alpha{f}$ (in $\mathbb{C}$)

Comment: @Roland if $f:B\to A$ is in the opposite category, then $f: A\to B$ in $\mathbb{C}$, thus for $\alpha : B\to C$ (in $\mathbb{C}$, note that you wrote $\alpha \in hom_\mathbb{C}(B,C)$ ) $\alpha\circ f : A\to C$ is perfectly well-defined

Comment: @Max I'm confused because if $f:B \to A$ in $\mathbb{C}^{op}$ then why wouldn't $f$ have a different name in $\mathbb{C}$ e.g. $f$ prime? $f^\prime:A \to B$ in $\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: @Roland in the usual formalism, they are literally equal, but some people like to write $f^{op}$ instead of $f$ for $f$ as seen in $\mathbb{C}^{op}$

Comment: The following question helped me understand: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2092872/do-opposite-categories-always-exist/2092955#2092955