# How to understand opposite category?

Tags: category-theory

Today I was explaining to my friend about opposite categories, and how the definition of monomorphism leads to defintion of epimorphism in opposite category. He asked me quite an interesting question. If we have a morphism in a category, how does that relate to the morphism in the opposite category?

For example, let's consider that category **Top**, and a homomorphism between two topological spaces. What would be exact expression for arrow in the opposite category?

I think it'd be something like the inverse function but I am not sure.

Comment: What do you mean?  For any category $\mathscr C$, a morphism $A\to B$ in the opposite category, $\mathscr C^{op}$ is just a $\mathscr C-$morphism from $B$ to $A$.

Comment: Thus, in your case, a morphism from $A$ to $B$  in the opposite category for Top is a continuous function from $B$ to $A$.

Comment: Now I mean the exact evaluation rule for the function. How would write down the set level expression for the opposite morphism?

Comment: The arrows are the same, only reversed. They don't need to have meanings as functions. The whole point of category theory is that there isn't necessarily a "function" meaning for arrows.

Comment: No idea what you mean.  What's the "set level expression" for a morphism in Top?  Whatever that is, it's the same for $\text{Top}^{op}$.

Comment: I dont understand your point but I think you understood my question @ThomasAndrews

Comment: "The function corresponding to a morphism in $\mathbf{Top}$" could be viewed as part of a functor $U : \mathbf{Top} \to \mathbf{Set}$ which acts on objects by taking a topological space to its underlying set of points.  There isn't really any close analog of a "concretization functor" $U : \mathbf{Top}^{op} \to \mathbf{Set}$.  Except, almost purely by chance, there *is* something kinda sorta close you can define in this case, which takes a topological space to its set of open sets, and acts on continuous functions $f : X \to Y$ by taking inverse images $f^{-1} : T_Y \to T_X$.

Comment: As @ThomasAndrews says, if the morphisms in the category correspond to some kind of function, that doesn't mean the morphisms in the opposite category will be functions with some other property. For example, a function from $\mathbb R\to\{0\}$ in the category of sets does not define an injective function in the opposite category. The arrow from $\{0\}\to\mathbb R$ is unspecified as a function.

Comment: I suspect you're assuming that morphisms in a category need to be "meaningful" in a particular (set-theoretic) way. This isn't the case, and the opposite category construction is "purely formal" in a sense; I think the discussion [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2092872/do-opposite-categories-always-exist/2092955#2092955) will be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is a bit underwhelming for some. I'm gonna give a practical answer and not get deep into philosophical aspects of this, but there are other interpretations to be given. You should consider this a simplification, but I believe it's a good one to start thinking about these concepts.

It may be convenient to think of the opposite category as the original category but where you draw the arrows backwards, and that's it.

It's just a formal device that helps us visualize and interpret certain concepts, and thus helps us with proofs as well.

We use this notion because it's easier to think this way but it shouldn't be necessary in principle. Human brains are not that powerful to do proofs without them, that's all.

In our case, if you have an arrow $f:a\rightarrow b$ in $Top$ and go to the opposite category, then $f^{op}:b\rightarrow a$ is not to be thought as a continuous function in $Top$ from $b$ to $a$, but as one from $a$ to $b$ too. It should be thought of as $f$ since nothing really changed.

Otherwise you can't really interpret it as a function. It's purely formal.

Comment: I don't think its true that "it shouldn't be necessary to in principle" to use the notion of opposite category. The notion of opposite category is fundamental and, in some sense, witnesses an important symmetry of categories. The opposite category construction assembles into an equivalence of 2-categories $\mathsf{Cat} \simeq \mathsf{Cat}^\mathsf{co}$.