# Contravariant functor defined by opposite category.

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, functors

Given $f,g$ as morphisms of objects in $C$, we denote them as $f',g'$ for $C^{op}$, and 
$$f\circ_C g = g'\circ_{C^{op}} f'.$$
For a contravariant functor $F$ from $C$ to $D$, we have $f:x\rightarrow y, g: y\rightarrow z$
$$F(g\circ_C f) = F(f) \circ_D F(g)$$
Why is this the same as a functor $F$ from $C^{op}$ to $D$? 
So given 
$$F(g' \circ_{C^{op}} f') = F(g')\circ_D F(f')$$
why is 
$$F(f) \circ_D F(g)= F(g')\circ_D F(f')?$$

**Edit:** If what I wrote doesn't make sense, can you point me to a reference? I see people say "the opposite category is used to define contravariant in a uniform way", but there is not any detail.

Comment: This what I found from here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/438694/definition-of-opposite-category      in the answer.

Comment: Yeah ok, dumb comment of me. But your notation is confusing. Let $f\in \text{Hom}_{C^{\text{op}}}(X,Y)$, by definition $f\in \text{Hom}_{C}(Y,X)$, no need to use $f'$.

Comment: **Please** make sure that you avoid typos **specially** in titles, which is the first thing people see of your question. We do judge books by their covers, you know...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your notation, note that
$$F(g' \circ_{C^{\mathrm{op}}} f') = F(f \circ_C g)$$
and not $F(g \circ_C f)$, and so you're trying to compare the wrong $D$-morphisms on the 8th line of your question (i.e. the equation after 'why is').

Treating $F$ as a covariant functor $C^{\mathrm{op}} \to D$, we have
$$F(g \circ_C f) = F(f' \circ_{C^{\mathrm{op}}} g') = F(f') \circ_D F(g')$$
which is the same result as when we considered $F$ as a contravariant function $C \to D$, since $f=f'$ and $g=g'$.

Comment: Ah I see, that typo got me really confused, but I did not know that $f = f'$ and $g=g'$, I will read more about this. Thank you.

Comment: Morphisms in $C^{\mathrm{op}}$ are morphisms in $C$, but their associated domain and codomain are the other way round. Specifically, suppose $f$ is a morphism in $C$ with domain $A$ and codomain $B$. Then $f$ is also a morphism in $C^{\mathrm{op}}$, but this time its domain is $B$ and its codomain is $A$. That's why I say $f=f'$.