# What exactly is a morphism in category theory?

Tags: category-theory, definition

Given a category $C$, an opposite category $C^{op}$ is defined as

- $ob(C^{op})=ob(C)$
- For every $x,y\in ob(C)$, $\text{Hom}_{C^{op}}(x,y)=\text{Hom}_C(y,x)$

One can informally think of this as reversing "arrows" in category $C$.

However, in most abstract sense, morphisms are not arrows. So how does reversing arrows correspond to definition of morphisms in $C^{op}$?

Things in $\text{Hom}_C(y,x)$ have a "source" $y$ and "target" $x$. Now these things become $\text{Hom}_{C^{op}}(x,y)$, but my mind keeps going in this way: surely things in $\text{Hom}_{C^{op}}(x,y)$ would have source $x$ and target $y$, so how does something with swapped sources/targets can be in this set?

Edit: Now I think I see what this is all about. So we don't really care what these morphisms are, but the important fact is that they must satisfy some rules regarding compositions etc. So what we really have is a consistent system of things that follow axioms, and that what we call $\text{Hom}$ sets (in particular they don't have sources or targets or even have to be arrows). In opposite category, we impose exactly same system of "morphisms" but just in opposite direction.

Comment: In $\mathfrak{Ab}^{op}$, the opposite category of $\mathfrak{Ab}$, the category of abelian groups, there are exactly two morphisms $\Bbb Z_2\to \Bbb Z$, and one going the other way. This is because there are exactly two group homomorphisms $\Bbb Z\to \Bbb Z_2$, and one going the other way.

Comment: What is your definition of an "arrow"? Typically in category theory, "arrow" and "morphism" are taken to be synonyms.

Comment: "In the most abstract sense, morphisms are not arrows" : to the contrary, morphisms are simply arrows. They don't have to he functions, mappings etc., they can simply be arrows, and so swapping the arrow really isn't a big deal

Comment: @DerekElkins I guess arrows in a sense of edges of directed graphs; I'm suggested think of directed graphs as a visualisation of axioms forced upon morphisms. I see that "reversing arrows" is probably enough description to see what opposite category is, but formal definition I'm given is the equality of Hom sets, which I can't quite relate to reversing arrows

Comment: If $f\in \operatorname{Hom}_{C}(x, y)$, then that means that $f$ is represented by an arrow in the directed graph that makes up $C$, and that arrow goes form $x$ to $y$. At the same time, $f$ is a morphism in $C^{op}$, where it is also represented by an arrow, but that arrow goes form $y$ to $x$.

Comment: The directionality of a morphism $f$ (i.e. the direction of its "arrow" in the category) is not something implicit to the kind of thing that $f$ is (say, a function from $X$ to $Y$) but how that thing is *used* in composition with other "arrows".

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Yep, I now get it. Now I can say that morphism $f:X\to Y$ and $f:Y\to X$ in $C$ and $C^{op}$ respectively are actually the same thing, but we just declared we are using them in opposite direction

Comment: @user160738 whoops, should have read the edit.  Yep!

Comment: It might be less confusing if you don't use the same symbols for $C$ and its opposite. Say you stick a little superscript op on everything. So instead of $ob(C^{op}) = ob(C)$ you say $ob(C^{op}) = \{ x^{op} : x  \in X \}$ where these $x^{op}$ are new things in bijection with the objects of $C$. Then you say the morphisms in $C^{op}$ are $\{f^{op} : f$ a morphism of $C\}$. You define $source(f^{op}) := target(f)^{op}$, $f^{op} \circ g^{op} := (g \circ f)^{op}$, etc. This is isomorphic to the definition you quoted but I find it psychologically easier to digest.

Answer (score 1):

The question has been answered multiple times on math.SE.

[What's the definition of morphism in a dual category?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2137916/whats-the-definition-of-morphism-in-a-dual-category)

[Do opposite categories always exist?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2092872/do-opposite-categories-always-exist)

[Maps in Opposite Categories](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/44768/maps-in-opposite-categories)

[Definition of opposite category](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/438694/definition-of-opposite-category)